# BASH: How do i store the value returned from a website into a varuable

Tags: bash, shell

This is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
x = $(curl www.google.com)
```

And this is the error after running the file called test.sh

```
MacBook-Pro:files user1$ ./test.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 19091    0 19091    0     0  58596      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 58561
./test.sh: line 2: x: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces which are present just before and after to the `=` symbol,

```
x=$(curl www.google.com)
```

Comment: so stupid... thanks a mil man. >_<
You have no idea how long i was trying to fix this